# WPF CompositeCollection

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm walking through the official WPF documentation, [How to: Implement a CompositeCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-a-compositecollection?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), there are some doubts about CollectionContainer.

```xml
<ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
         <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource greekGods}" />
         <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource greekHeroes}}" />
         <ListBoxItem Background="red">Other ListBox Item 1</ListBoxItem>
         <ListBoxItem Background="red">Other ListBox Item 2</ListBoxItem>
     </CompositeCollection>
</ListBox.ItemsSource>
```

Why dose XMLDataProvider resource `GreekHeroesData` have to use Binding? otherwise it'll throw an exception.

```xml
<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource greekHeroes}}" />
```

but CLR resource `GreekGodsData` may ignore it?

```xml
<CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource greekGods}" />
```

Thanks for your help!

When I Write with the following:

```xml
 <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource greekHeroes}" />
```

it raised an exception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=“An exception was thrown while setting the property 'System.Windows.Data.CollectionContainer.Collection'.”, the line number is "49", and the line position is "22".
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at CompositeCollections.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in I:\github.com\learning-wpf\DataBinding\CompositeCollections\MainWindow.xaml : line 1

  This exception was initially thrown in this call stack:
    [external code]

Internal exception 1:
ArgumentException: 'System.Windows.Data.XmlDataProvider' is not a valid value for property 'Collection'.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `greekGods` and `greekHeroes` are of different types.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why dose XMLDataProvider resource **GreekHeroesData** have to use Binding?

- As you see in your document link, in their XAML, they define [XmlDataProvider][1] that mean you can create your data in XAML file instead your View Model -> therefore GreekHeroesData have to use Binding

2. CLR resource **GreekGodsData** may ignore it?

- **GreekGodsData** they get from another Resources filfe (clr-namespace:SDKSample), so need to use **Static Resource** to get it.

3. When I Write with the following it raised an exception?

- As my explain above, greekHeroes is define by XmlDataProvider so you **must** be you **Binding** to get its data.
  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider?view=windowsdesktop-7.0